# Error instantiating Texture2D in MonoGame for Windows 8 Metro Apps

Tags: xna, monogame, sharpdx, windows-8

I have an game which builds for WindowsGL and Windows8. The WindowsGL works fine, but the Windows8 build throws an error when trying to instantiate a new Texture2D.

The Code:

```
var texture = new Texture2D(CurrentGame.SpriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, width, 1); // Error thrown here...
texture.setData(FunctionThatReturnsColors());
```

[You can find the rest of the code on Github](https://github.com/JimmyBoh/BrewmasterEngine).

The Error:

```
SharpDX.SharpDXException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [Unknown], ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], Message: The parameter is incorrect.

  Source=SharpDX
  StackTrace:
       at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
       at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateTexture2D(Texture2DDescription& descRef, DataBox[] initialDataRef, Texture2D texture2DOut)
       at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D..ctor(Device device, Texture2DDescription description)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D..ctor(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean mipmap, SurfaceFormat format, Boolean renderTarget)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D..ctor(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at BrewmasterEngine.Graphics.Content.Gradient.CreateHorizontal(Int32 width, Color left, Color right) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\BrewmasterEngine\Graphics\Content\Gradient.cs:line 16
       at SampleGame.Menu.Widgets.GradientBackground.UpdateBounds(Object sender, EventArgs args) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\SampleGame\Menu\Widgets\GradientBackground.cs:line 39
       at SampleGame.Menu.Widgets.GradientBackground..ctor(Color start, Color stop, Int32 scrollamount, Single scrollspeed, Boolean horizontal) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\SampleGame\Menu\Widgets\GradientBackground.cs:line 25
       at SampleGame.Scenes.IntroScene.Load(Action done) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\SampleGame\Scenes\IntroScene.cs:line 23
       at BrewmasterEngine.Scenes.Scene.LoadScene(Action`1 callback) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\BrewmasterEngine\Scenes\Scene.cs:line 89
       at BrewmasterEngine.Scenes.SceneManager.Load(String sceneName, Action`1 callback) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\BrewmasterEngine\Scenes\SceneManager.cs:line 69
       at BrewmasterEngine.Scenes.SceneManager.LoadDefaultScene(Action`1 callback) in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\BrewmasterEngine\Scenes\SceneManager.cs:line 83
       at BrewmasterEngine.Framework.Game2D.LoadContent() in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\BrewmasterEngine\Framework\Game2D.cs:line 117
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Initialize()
       at BrewmasterEngine.Framework.Game2D.Initialize() in c:\Projects\Personal\GitHub\BrewmasterEngine\BrewmasterEngine\Framework\Game2D.cs:line 105
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run(GameRunBehavior runBehavior)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MetroFrameworkView`1.Run()
  InnerException:
```

Is this an error that needs to be solved in MonoGame, or is there something that I need to do differently in my engine and game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an issue in MonoGame, if it was properly supporting the GraphicsProfiles introduced in XNA 4.0 the MaxTextureSize would be 2048 for `Reach` and 4096 for `HiDef`. You can check the Capabiities of your hardware by querying through SharpDX directly. Once you have access to a `D3D9Driver` instance, you'll have to create this yourself as I don't think there's a way to get from MonoGame, use the `D3D9DeviceCaps` to query the `MaxTextureWidth` and `MaxTextureHeight`.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Turns out the issue was not initializing and loading content in the correct order.</s> I am building an engine and had to refactor it to work as a library for Windows 8 apps. When I shuffled some code around I removed some XNA-specific code and put in back in the wrong place.

Here's the basic flow of things:

1. `Constructor`

   - Instantiate `GraphicsDeviceManage`
   - Set `Content.RootDirectory` (optional)
2. `Initialize`

   - Update graphics options (optional)
3. `LoadContent`

   - Instantiate `SpriteBatch`, using your `GraphicsDeviceManage` from before
   - Load the content for the game.

**Update:**

The actual error was that the texture I was trying to create was too big on the Surface RT. After looking in to it a bit, this is related to the graphics card and driver. My Surface RT has a limit of 2048(2<sup>11</sup>), but my laptop goes up to 8192(2<sup>13</sup>).

Here is a snippet that allows you to determine the maximum texture size based on each device and 'caches' the result. (PLEASE update it if you know a more elegant way!)

```
/// <summary>
/// Max texture size supported by the current device.
/// </summary>
public static int MaxTextureSize
{
   get
    {
        if (maxTextureSize == 0)
            maxTextureSize = CalculateMaxTextureSize();
         return maxTextureSize;
    }
}
private static int maxTextureSize;
private static int CalculateMaxTextureSize()
{
    var maxSize = 0;
    var i = 8;
    while (i < 20)
    {
        try
        {
            var size = (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
            new Texture2D(SpriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, size, 1);
            maxSize = size;

            size++;
            new Texture2D(SpriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, size, 1);
            maxSize = size;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxSize;
}
```

If you know the maximum size of a texture then you can just scale accordingly!